# Problem on Continuity of function

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if f is a continuous function on [-1, 1] such that f (x) < 1 for all x, then there exists
$k \in N$ such that $f (x) < (k - 1)/k$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$

I am just wondering what is wrong with my reasoning here:

Let a := 1-f(x) >0 since f(x) <1

Using Archimedean Property, we can find a k such that 0< $\frac{1}{k}<$ a.

Then we will have f(x) < 1 - 1/k.

However, I have not used the property of continuity here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $a$ depends on $x$ so also $k$ depends on $x$ and then it isn't unique.

Now let's give a proof: $f$ is continuous on the compact then it's bounded above by say $M$ and attains this maximum. We have $M<1$ so we can find $k$ such that
$$M<(k-1)/k<1$$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $\frac {k} {k-1}$ has limit $1$ as $k$ tends to infinity and use $a$ in the question.

In your reasoning $k$ depends on $x$, but in question $k$ is independent of $x$.

We need continuity to make sure that $f$ attain its maximum which is strictly less than $1$ and hence we can choose an "uniform" $k$.

Comment: always welcome . . .